# Elasticsearch pagination on multiple types in same index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to set pagination for multiple types when searching across multiple types in single index.  I am able to set pagination for total records but my criteria is to set for pagination for 2 different types. Can anyone suggest pls?

Request:-

```
GET /testindex/txnentity,sampletxn/_search?pretty=true
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "_all"
            ],
            "query": "Tester*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 30
}
```

Usecase:-

```
txnentity --> pagination for 5 records
sampletxn --> pagination for 10 records
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying over several types in a single query, the pagination cannot be segregated by type. If you want to do that you need to send a [multi-search query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) with two queries, one for each type and with the appropriate pagination:

```
POST testindex/_msearch
{"type" : "txnentity"}
{"size": 5,  "query": {"bool": {"must": [{"query_string": {"fields": ["_all"],"query": "Tester*"}}]}}}
{"type" : "sampletxn"}
{"size": 10, "query": {"bool": {"must": [{"query_string": {"fields": ["_all"],"query": "Tester*"}}]}}}
```

Comment: Yes, this helps.  Accepting this as answer for my query.